# Amazon Coretto 11, Spring Boot and PowerMock - tests failing

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, powermock

I have a java based Spring Boot project that uses PowerMock to mock static methods and contructor invocations where necessary
Since upgrading to the latest version of IntelliJ - I need to use a JDK version greater than JDK 8
I moved to Amazon Coretto as I want to deploy my app on the latest support JDK on AWS Elastic Beanstalk
When I upgraded and ran my tests, I started hitting issues
After following this thread - https://github.com/java-decompiler/jd-gui/issues/187 and using this PowerMockIgnore syntax

```
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.", "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.", "javax.xml.", "org.xml.", "org.w3c.dom.", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.", "javax.activation.*", "javax.xml.transform.*", "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.*")
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.lang.Class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @d5ce97f
    at org.powermock.core.classloader.DeferSupportingClassLoader.findResource(DeferSupportingClassLoader.java:154)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findResource(ClassLoader.java:1342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Module.getResourceAsStream(Module.java:1575)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.serialization.deserialization.builtins.BuiltInsResourceLoader.loadResource(BuiltInsResourceLoader.java:27)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.descriptors.runtime.components.ReflectKotlinClassFinder.findBuiltInsData(ReflectKotlinClassFinder.kt:52)
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.internal.impl.builtins.jvm.JvmBuiltInsPackageFragmentProvider.findPackage(JvmBuiltInsPackageFragmentProvider.kt:60)
```

This has had me stumped for days now. Can anyone offer any further suggestions on what I could try

Regards
Damien

Comment: just a thought, did you added
            <scope>test</scope> (or the gradle equivalent)
to the power mock dependency? because it shouldn't event be loading when running the code

Comment: good question - it is scoped as test

Comment: You don't need an `*` at the end of all of those Strings? For instance, shouldn't it be `javax.management.*` instead of `javax.management.`?

Comment: Unfortunately I tried that and get this error now - java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected java.lang.Class jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String,boolean) throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException accessible: module java.base does not "opens jdk.internal.loader" to unnamed module @35088e87

Comment: the _only_ way for someone to give you proper help is for you to prove a minimal reproducible example, like a github project that shows your problem. Then, poeple might be able to help a lot more than you think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not find a solution to get PowerMock to work with Java 11 so I have removed it from my project

Comment: I wanted to say if you are using spring you have:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reflection-test-utils
you can do everything powermock can with that...

Answer (score 0):

Change your version in Gradle:

```
testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: "org.mockito", module: "mockito-core"
    }
    testCompile("org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4")
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but this did not work